# UV Mapping looks messed up after unwrapping

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I just marked the seams and unwrapped this human mesh. After I unwrap it, it looks like this ...

[image: Image of the result]

[image: Mesh from different sides, with the seams marked with red]

I have no idea why this is happening. Please ask, if you need further information.

Answer (score 0):

The red UVs you can see in the UV editor are pinned. You must have accidentally pressed <kbd>p</kbd> with UVs selected. This means that they will be kept in place unmoved when you perform unwrap. To remove pining you need to select pinned UVs(or just all UVS with <kbd>a</kbd>)and hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in the UV Editor. Once you do that Unwrap will work as you would expect.

Pinning is very useful if you for example wanted to manually define the border of some UV island or straighten some lines and then recalculate UV unwrap based on the UVs staying in place and shape you pinned them to.

Answer (score -1):

My best guess is that you havent selected all the verticies and that it is only selecting the verts you can see. To select all verts either press "a" to select everything, or make sure you are in edit mode and tick or untick the box on the same bar as the edit mode button that says limit selection to visible, then press b to draw a box and draw a box around everything you want selected with the mouse, then unwrap. Though Im not an expert in blender so I could be wrong !